# How can I fixed: Method App\Http\Controllers\UserDashboard::view does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I was building a user management project, everything seems going smooth untill I began to see this error:
**Method App\Http\Controllers\UserDashboard::view does not exist.**
**Bad Method Call
Did you mean App\Http\Controllers\UserDashboard::validate() ?**

[image]

Here's the UserDashboard Controller:

```
public function profile() {

        $title = "Profile";

        return $this->view('user.profile', compact('title'));
    }

    public function profileSettings() {

        $title = "Profile Settings";

        return $this->view('user.settings', compact('title'));
    }

    public function plans() {

        $title = "Plans";
        return $this->view('user.plans', compact('title'));
    }

    public function forum() {


        $title = "Forum";

        return $this->view('user.forum', compact('title'));
    }

    public function resources() {


        $title = "Resources";

        return $this->view('user.resources', compact('title'));
    }

    public function marketplace() {


        $title = "Marketplace";

        return $this->view('user.marketplace', compact('title'));
    }


    public function transactions() {


        $title = "Transactions";

        return $this->view('user.marketplace', compact('title'));
    }

    public function invoice_list() {


        $title = "Invoice List";

        return $this->view('user.invoice_list', compact('title'));
    }
```

Now, on the same UserDashboard controller, the *dashboard* method is working, and other methods from other controllers also work.

Here's my route:

```
Route::get('/dashboard', [UserDashboard::class, 'dashboard'])->name('dashboard');
Route::get('/dashboard/profile', [UserDashboard::class, 'profile'])->name('user_profile');
Route::get('/dashboard/settings', [UserDashboard::class, 'settings'])->name('user_settings');
Route::get('/dashboard/forum', [UserDashboard::class, 'forum'])->name('user_forum');
Route::get('/dashboard/resources', [UserDashboard::class, 'resources'])->name('user_resources');
Route::get('/dashboard/marketplace', [UserDashboard::class, 'marketplace'])->name('user_marketplace');

Route::get('/dashboard/plans', [UserDashboard::class, 'plans'])->name('user_plans');

Route::get('/dashboard/invoice_list', [UserDashboard::class, 'invoice_list'])->name('user_invoice');
Route::get('/dashboard/transactions', [UserDashboard::class, 'transactions'])->name('user_transactions');
```

So I cannot visit /dashboard/forum and all other routes except dashboard without the error
How can I fix this, please??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the controller doesn't have view() method, you can't call $this->view().

The right way is:

```
return view('user.profile', compact('title'));
```

Comment: thank you it works. I started learning Laravel, more used to custom mvc. Thanks